# Is it possible to check if a variable fulfills logical expression stored as a string?

Tags: python

If I have a variable

```
dummy = 'abc'
```

And a dictionary where I keep different logical OR expressions where OR is represented by `|`.

```
logic_dict = {'1':'def|how', '2':'does|this', '3':'abc|hi'}
```

I would want to compare the logical expressions against the fixed variable in some way, the following for loop does not work, but it shows how I would ideally want to do it.

```
for test_number,logic_string in logic_dict.items():
    print(dummy == logic_string)
```

Which I would want to output

```
False
False
True
```

I know that I can do this manually by writing

```
print(dummy == 'def' or dummy == 'how')
print(dummy == 'does' or dummy == 'this')
print(dummy == 'abc' or dummy =='hi')
```

But Is there a way to do this with the string representation of the logical expression?

Comment: That's not how you do it manually. It should be `print(dummy == 'def' or dummy == 'how')`

Comment: Sorry, you are right, edited.

Comment: Split the string, and use `in`.

Comment: BTW, a dictionary whose keys are sequential numbers should probably be a list.

Comment: Note that @Barmar's suggestion is as easy as `print(dummy in logic_string.split('|'))`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure how you set yourself up for this situation, and I'm pretty sure there's a way to properly avoid such convoluted logical clause parsing, but for what it's worth, here's how you can deal with the specific use-case at hand:

```
dummy = 'abc'
logic_dict = {'1':'def|how', '2':'does|this', '3':'abc|hi'}

for test_number,logic_string in logic_dict.items():
    print(dummy in logic_string.split('|'))
```

Note of warning: This whole concept goes haywire (and the suggested solution is appropriately worthless) if your string includes a `|` character...